# How can I calculate the coefficients of the prblem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have to solve the following initial and boundary value problem:
$$u_t=u_{xx}, 0<x<L, t>0$$
$$u(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=x, 0<x<L$$

I have done the following:

Using the method of Separation of Variables, the solution is of the form: $u(x,t)=X(x) \cdot T(t)$
Replacing this at $(1)$, we get the following two problems:
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
X''+\lambda X=0, 0<x<L\\ 
X(0)=X'(L)=0
\end{matrix}\right\}(2)$$
and
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
T'+ \lambda T=0, t>0
\end{matrix}\right\}(3)$$

$$u(x,0)=X(x)T(0)=x$$

Solving the problem $(2)$ we get:
$$X_n(x)=\sin{(\frac{(2n+1) \pi x}{2L})}, n=0,1,2,3, \dots$$
and solving the problem $(3)$ we get:
$$T_n(t)=A_n e^{-(\frac{(2n+1) \pi}{2L})^2t}, n=0,1,2,3, \dots$$
The solution is of the form:
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{A_n \sin{(\frac{(2n+1) \pi x}{2L})} e^{-(\frac{(2n+1) \pi}{2L})^2t}}$$
$$u(x,0)=x \Rightarrow x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{A_n \sin{(\frac{(2n+1) \pi x}{2L})}}$$

Is this correct so far?

How can I calculate the coefficients $A_n$?

Comment: diffrentiation one by one, and applying the ODE for every n (since each sine func has different ratio.

Comment: @Snufsan I haven't understood... :/ Can't we use the Fourier series or the Sturm-Liouville theory?

Comment: You know that the solution fulfills the equation $u_t = u_{xx}$ so just differentiate one by one the sum and you get an ode for each cofficient $A_n$ ($A_n$ is actually $A_n(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we find $A_n$ by:

$A_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^Lx\sin(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L})dx$

$=\frac{2}{L}(-\frac{2L}{(2n+1)\pi})[x\cos(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L})|^L_0]+\frac{2}{L}(\frac{2L}{(2n+1)\pi})\int_0^L\cos(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L})dx$

$=\frac{2}{L}(\frac{2L}{(2n+1)\pi})(-L\cos(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}))+\frac{2}{L}(\frac{2L}{(2n+1)\pi})^2(\sin(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2L})|^L_0)$

$=-\frac{4L}{(2n+1)\pi}\cos(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2})+\frac{2}{L}(\frac{2L}{(2n+1)\pi})^2\sin(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2})$

$=(-1)^n\frac{2}{L}(\frac{2L}{(2n+1)\pi})^2$

Comment: So we use the Fourier series?

Comment: Yes I believe so :)

Comment: Ok!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)